# How to manage multiple Dockerfiles in one project (Best practice)

Tags: docker

I have Dockerfile for my project, but I want to manage many Dockerfiles depends on the Cuda version.

```
Dockerfile1:
# Get the base Ubuntu image from Docker Hub and update packages.
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
# Install prerequisites
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

Dockerfile2:
# Get the base Ubuntu image from Docker Hub and update packages.
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
# Install prerequisites
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Tue question is not clear, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a variable before. It will be something like this:

```
ARG CUDA_VERSION='10.2'
# Get the base Ubuntu image from Docker Hub and update packages.
FROM nvidia/cuda:$CUDA_VERSION-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04
# Install prerequisites
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```